# Snowflakes warehouse sizing

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Plan for snowflakes cost optimization to an existing setup.

1.Disable the unused users/roles and drop the unused warehouses.

2.Monitor the warehouse closely and take actions as per results .Below is the approach that I like to go, to monitor a warehouse XXXXXX.Please review and pass on your comments.

a. Get the report on credits used by the warehouse in  last 14 days

> select * from
>   table(information_schema.warehouse_metering_history(dateadd('day',-14,current_timestamp()),current_timestamp()))
>   and WAREHOUSE_NAME='XXXXXX';

-Concentrate the time frame during which we see high credit usage for the warehouse and note the time frame .

-check for AVG_RUNNING ,AVG_QUEUE_LOAD ,AVG_QUEUE_LOAD ,AVG_QUEUE_LOAD  for the time period using step b.

b.Get the below report on no.of queries and their status  in last 14 days on  a warehouse

> select * from
>   table(information_schema.warehouse_load_history(date_range_start=>dateadd('day',-14,current_timestamp())))
>   and WAREHOUSE_NAME='XXXXXX';

-if the values for  AVG_QUEUE_LOAD,AVG_QUEUE_PROVISION  are high during the time frame that we noticed in stap a, then try increasing the size of warehouse(scale up).

-if values for AVG_BLOCKED is high, then try increasing the warehouse cluster(scale out).

-If we see AVG_QUEUE_LOAD,AVG_QUEUE_PROVISION,AVG_BLOCKED Zero or less value ,then try decreasing the size of the warehouse.

c.Get the ratio of avg_running and CREDITS_USED

> with cte as (   select date_trunc('hour', start_time) as start_time,
>   end_time, warehouse_name, credits_used   from
>   table(information_schema.warehouse_metering_history(dateadd('days',-1,current_date()),current_date()))
>   where warehouse_name = 'XXXXXX') select date_trunc('hour',
>   a.start_time) as start_time, avg(AVG_RUNNING), avg(credits_used),
>   avg(AVG_RUNNING) / avg(credits_used) * 100  from
>   table(information_schema.warehouse_load_history(dateadd('days',-1,current_date()),current_date()))
>   a join cte b on a.start_time = date_trunc('hour', a.start_time) where
>   a.warehouse_name = 'XXXXXX' group by 1 order by 1;

-If the ratio is high ,then don't make the changes to warehouse size.

-If the ratio is low, then consider reducing the size of warehouse.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you take a look at this post on Snowflake's documentation:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-considerations.html#scaling-up-vs-scaling-out

Some of the metrics that you are using (like queuing) relate to whether you need to scale out, not up.  This goes for avg_running, as well, for the most part.  Reducing the size of the warehouse doesn't affect the number of queries that will execute on that warehouse, but rather the performance at which they execute.  You should look into things like bytes spilled to local or remote storage more...to determine whether the warehouse is too small for the queries being executed on that server.

This is a tricky topic, which is MUCH different from other databases out there.  I would recommend a good read of that document, and if necessary, maybe reach out directly to Snowflake for some professional services assistance.